# Align elements at bottom of div

Tags: html, css

I want each button "Read more" of each div to be aligned in the same level (and in this case at the bottom of the div). The problem is that I don't want to give a specific height to the divs and neither change any markup or style.

I could use a bunch of pseudo class selectors but I would like to keep the code simple and maybe there's a simpler way.

[Here's the working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aLbu6frL/)

```
.btn{
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;  
font-weight: 400px;
padding: 5px 10px;
border: 2px solid #1AC4F8;
color: #1AC4F8;
cursor: pointer;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution entails using flexbox and absolute positioning:

https://jsfiddle.net/aLbu6frL/6/

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-bottom:40px;
}
.column {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.btn-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Flexbox can do that.

It will set all the columns to equal height and tell the button to be at the bottom of each column.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
#services {
  background-color: rgb(265, 265, 265);
  color: #424242;
}
#services .col-3 {
  text-align: left;
  float: none;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#sevices h3 {
  margin: 10px 0
}
.btn {
  margin-top: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid #1AC4F8;
  color: #1AC4F8;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.8s, background-color 0.8s;
  transition: color 0.8s, background-color 0.8s
}
```

```html
<section id="services">
  <!-- Services Starts Here -->
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>SERVICES</h2>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <h3>Consulting and audit</h3>
        <p>Get help to accelerate your company online from our highly experienced specialists. It is as good as it sounds!</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <h3>Web Development</h3>
        <p>Professional custom e-commerce and web design to let your business grow at a rapid pace. See how we do that.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 right-align">
        <h3>Search Engine Optimization</h3>
        <p>Want to be on Page 1 of Google and Bing? Read about our SEO services that drive more potential customers.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 right-align">
        <h3>Pay Per Click Management</h3>
        <p>Attract highly relevant audience with Google Adwords, Display, Retargeting, Facebook, YouTube, Twitter.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, I've made the following amendments:

```
.btn{
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;  
        font-weight: 400px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border: 2px solid #1AC4F8;
        color: #1AC4F8;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.8s, background-color 0.8s;
        transition: color 0.8s, background-color 0.8s;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
    }
    .wrapper {
       position: relative;
    }
```

- added `position: absolute;` to your `btn` class
- added `bottom: 0px` to compliment the position (again to the `btn` class)
- added `position: relative;` to a `wrapper` class so `btn` knows what it is positioning itself within.

You may need to update your existing CSS to adjust to the changes.

**Updated Fork:**

https://jsfiddle.net/exaboofu/

Answer (score 0):

Please add some more CSS in your existing and your button align with bottom please look below CSS code:

```
    #services .right-align h3, #services .right-align p{
        text-align: right;
    }
    #services .right-align .btn{
        text-align:left;
    }

    .btn{
        bottom: 0;
        position:absolute;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set p tag a min-height. I just try it and it work's for me see sample code below. You can set p tag height based on your need.

```
#services .row .col-3 p {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```